# Laravel 5 Eloquent query reuse issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5 eloquent query but getting some technical issue which I can't figure out. I want to extract two separate array from the same query having bit different condition for both like this:

```
$articles = DB::table($this->table)
                ->select('articles.id','art.name');

$simpleTypes =  $articles->whereIn('articles.content_type',['Type 1','Type 2','Type 3'])->get();

$complexTypes = $articles->whereIn('articles.content_type',['Type 4','Type 5'])->get();
```

Getting data in `$simpleTypes` but not getting in `$complexTypes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clone the original query to reuse it:

```
$articles = DB::table($this->table)
                ->select('articles.id','art.name');

$clonedQuery = clone $article;

$simpleTypes =  $articles->whereIn('articles.content_type',['Type 1','Type 2','Type 3'])->get();

$complexTypes = $clonedQuery->whereIn('articles.content_type',['Type 4','Type 5'])->get();
```

Comment: Have Done bro :)